# Проблема с переопределением std::function

Tags: winapi, c++11, c++

и снова доброго вечера всем форумчанам.
Возникла проблема с переопределением объектов std::function<void()>
и будто вещь это не особо сложная, а разобраться никак не получается.
есть у меня некоторый класс:

```
введите код здесь
#include <functional>
class ProcessEventHandler
{
public: 
      std::function<void()> ProcessCrashHandler;
      std::function<void()> ProcessStopHandler;
};
```

с его помощью я буду реализовывать Колбек в следующий класс

```
class ProcessManager : public ProcessEventHandler
{
public:
ProcessManager(const std::string &sFilePath);
ProcessManager(const _int32 &ProcessID);
~ProcessManager();
............
private:
 void onProcessStart();
 void onProcessWatch();
 void onProcessCrash();
 void onProcessStopped();
 void onProcessManulyStop();
...........
};
```

проблема заключается в том, что для объектов

```
   std::function<void()> ProcessCrashHandler;
   std::function<void()> ProcessStopHandler;
```

в классе потомке нужно присвоить функции

```
void onProcessCrash();
void onProcessStopped();
```

пытаюсь это сделать в конструкторе

```
  ProcessManager::ProcessManager(const std::string &sFilePath) :
  m_ppiProcInfo(),
  m_sCommandLine(sFilePath),
  m_isRunning(false)
  {
  ProcessCrashHandler = onProcessCrash;  
  ProcessStopHandler = &ProcessManager::onProcessStopped;

  m_pcEventLoger = new EventLogger(getCurrentDirPath());
  onProcessStart();
   }
```

я как только уже не пробовал ничего не получается, через лямда пробовал тоже не получилось. не могу понять то ли у меня руки кривые, или с компилятором-то не в порядке
Помогите пожалуйста

ошибки

```
 error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)  
 error C3867: 'ProcessManager::onProcessCrash': function call missing argument list; use '&ProcessManager::onProcessCrash' to create a pointer to member
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не-не, так не пойдёт.

Дело в том, что `onProcessCrash` — не функция! Поэтому вы не сможете сохранить её не только в переменной типа `std::function<void(void)>`, но даже обыкновенному указателю на функцию типа `void (*)(void)`.

На самом деле это функция-член, для её вызова вам нужен конкретный `this`. Привязка `this` осуществляется просто: при помощи `std::bind`.

Попробуйте так:

```
ProcessCrashHandler = std::bind(&ProcessManager::onProcessCrash, this);
```